# Return search results based on matches, not by ID

Tags: javascript, json

Upon form submit, I am trying to return a match of the JSON, and not just search for a specific ID.

However, unsure of how I could lay this out. I have the functionality to search for the required match in a js document within one of my node modules, but unsure how to get this working.

Here is the exact line of code I am referring to:

```
  const ELS_form = document.getElementByID('element');
```

Here is all the code within a script tag:

```
 async function onFormSubmit(ev) {ev.preventDefault();
 const EL_form = ev.currentTarget;
                return (await fetch(EL_form.action)).json();
                    }
                                  
 const ELS_form = document.getElementByID('element');
 ELS_form.forEach((el) => el.addEventListener("submit", (ev) => {
 onFormSubmit(ev).then(res => console.log(res));
                    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is `getElementById` and not `getElementByID`. And I am assuming you have to submit a form with `id`, in that case, there is no need for `forEach` for adding event lister.

Modified your code based on my understanding with sample `Form Action`, it may be useful for you.

```js
async function onFormSubmit(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    let EL_form = ev.currentTarget;
    return (await fetch(EL_form.action)).json();
}

const ELS_form = document.getElementById('element');
ELS_form.addEventListener("submit", (ev) => {
    onFormSubmit(ev).then(res => console.log(res));
});
```

```html
<form id="element" action="https://fakestoreapi.com/products/1">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```